# Are Ruby Ractors the Same as Python's MultiProcessing module?

Tags: python, ruby, multithreading, multiprocessing, gil

The Ruby 3.0 release has introduced Ractors and the way they're represented along their examples, brings Python's MultiProcessing module into mind.

So...

1. Are Ruby's Ractors just multiple processes in disguise and the GIL is still ruling over the threads?
2. If they aren't, could you provide an example in which Ractors have the upper hand against MultiProcessing in both speed and communication latency?
3. Can Ractors be as fast as C/C++ threads and with low latency?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Are Ruby's Ractors just multiple processes in disguise and the GIL is still ruling over the threads?

The Ractor specification does not prescribe any particular implementation strategy. It most certainly does not prescribe that an implementor must use OS processes. In fact, while that would be a pretty simple implementation because the OS does all the hard work for you, it would also be a pretty stupid implementation because Ractors are meant to be light-weight, which OS processes are typically not.

So, I expect that every implementor will choose their own most efficient implementation strategy. For example, I would expect TruffleRuby's and JRuby's implementation to be based on something like Kilim or Project Loom, Opal's implementation to be based on WebWorkers, Realms, and Promises, Artichoke's implementation to be based on Actix, Riker, or Axiom, and *maybe* MRuby's implementation *might* even be based on OS processes because of MRuby's focus on simplicity.

Right at this very moment, there does not exist *any* production-ready implementation of Ractors. In fact, there *cannot be* a production-ready implementation of Ractors, because the Ractor specification itself is still experimental, and thus not finalized.

The only implementation in existence right now is Koichi Sasada's original prototype which currently ships with YARV 3.0.0. This implementation does *not* implement Ractors as processes, it implements them as OS threads. YARV does not have a GIL, but it does have a per-Ractor GVL. So, only one thread of a Ractor can run at the same time, but multiple Ractors can each run one thread at the same time.

However, this is not a very optimized implementation, only a prototype. I would expect TruffleRuby's or JRuby's implementation to not have any sort of global lock. They never had one before, and Ractors don't share any data, so there simply is nothing to lock in the first place.

> 2. If they aren't, could you provide an example in which Ractors have the upper hand against MultiProcessing in both speed and communication latency?

This comparison doesn't make much sense. First of all, Ractor is a specification with potentially multiple implementations, whereas to my understanding, Python's multiprocessing module is simply a way of starting multiple Python interpreters.

Secondly, Ractors are a language feature with specific language semantics.

> 3. Can Ractors be as fast as C/C++ threads and with low latency?

It's not quite clear what you mean by this. C doesn't have threads, so asking about C threads doesn't make sense. C++ has threads, but just like Ractors, they are simply a specification with multiple possible implementations. It will simply depend on the particular implementation of Ractors and C++ threads.

It is certainly possible to implement Ractors using threads. The current YARV prototype is proof of that.

Answer (score 1):

I found an [article](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/performance/how-fast-are-ractors.html) on FastRuby's website that explains the differences between Ractors & other Concurrency & Parallelism features of Ruby.

The whole point was that, they're not fast enough YET (30/12/2020) and are lacking behind `fork` and even `threads` so far. So the answer so far is:

1. No
2. Unfortunately, not YET (30/12/2020)
3. No (Then again, not YET! But I'd really be happy if they finally could)